# PHP $POST If statement

Tags: php, facebook, post

Okay, so the issue i am having is that i have a simple textarea that should sent what is entered to another page, it should say 'Thanks' when submitted, and should prompt for entry if nothing is entered, however, when i enter nothing it still says 'Thanks'

Im sure it will be simple enough. Here is the code from my index.php

```
<form method="POST" action="translate.php">
<name="status" cols="50" rows="5">
What's on your mind?
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Translate my Status" />
```

and my translate.php

```
<?php

$status = $_POST['status'];
if($status == ""){
echo "Please enter a status.";
}
else {
echo "Thanks";
}

?>
```

i have tried using the above code in my index.php but got an error for the 'status' variable.

while i am asking, how would i go about having a popup error on the main page rather than it redirecting to the translate.php

Comment: `if( (isset($_POST['status'])) && ($_POST['status']!='') )` THANKS

Comment: that got the first if to work, but now it asks for a status no matter what i enter

Comment: did you update your form as Ashwini Agarwal suggested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You forgot to write `textarea`.

```
<textarea name="status" cols="50" rows="5">
What's on your mind?
</textarea><br>
```

2.Textarea will have `What's on your mind?` as default. So you should check..

```
if(($status == "") || ($status == "What's on your mind?"))
```

3.Try `echo $status` to see what it is actually containing?

Comment: i had changed the textarea name to just name to see if that was causing problems. I have added the and to the if but still just says thanks when i enter nothing and 'What's on your mind?'

Comment: `added the and to the if` not `and` its `or`.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I took your advice and removed the default text, and i removed the statement from the if statement that says or 'What's on your mind' and it works perfect. many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form name="frm" method="POST" action="translate.php">
 <script language="javascript">
 function submitData()
 {
       if(document.frm.status.value == "")
          alert("Please enter a status.");
       else
          frm.submit();
 }
 </script>
 What's on your mind?
 <textarea name="status" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea><br>
 <input type="button" value="Translate my Status" onclick="submitData()"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The if statement is not appropriate, it doesn't actually do what you expect. 
Here's your code updated:

```
<form method="POST" action="translate.php">
<textarea name="status" cols="50" rows="5">
What's on your mind?
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Translate my Status" />
</form>
```

and your translate.php

```
<?php
$status = $_POST['status'];
if(isset($status) && strlen($status)>0){
echo "Thanks";
}
else {
echo "Please enter a status.";
}
?>
```

Comment: logic is wrong way around. Says thanks if not set OR empty

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better with `<textarea name="status" cols="50" rows="5">`.

You also set a value to the textarea, so if you don't remove "What's on your mind?", it means you are sending that value through status, therefore, it is not empty.

If it still show "Thanks" when you removed that value, there might be an other problem.